# Anchor Text Hiding DocuSIgn

Tags: docusignapi

I have one Anchor Text in my text control(Richedit control, `<<Signed_1>>` for first user, `<<Signed_2>>` for second etc. In DocuSign 
I want to Hide that `<<Signed_1>>` and replace the corresponding Sign Tab.

I tried to set `forecolor` as White for both and convert it to `bytearray` and send to DocuSign(using Rest API). But that tags are not in white color they are having normal black color font why this happened?

Comment: Is your source document created using MS Word? You need to put `white text on white background` and when you will send this document to DocuSign via API, then DocuSign will keep the color and background of text as it is.

Comment: Im getting the text from RichEditControl and Convert that to Byte Array, that byte array is passing as Document using RestAPI

Comment: I would verify what format you get as output.  It sounds like your Byte Array effectively contains plain text.  Another way to ask:  What is the mime-type/content-type/file extension of the document?

Comment: Can you share a sample file with us?

Answer (score 0):

The anchorText is a string of text that you used to indicate to DocuSign where you would like the tag placed. It is part of your source document. You can change its color to white by changing the document you send to DocuSign. The actual tag color is a different thing altogether and it is used for some tag types to control how they are viewed in the completed document (for example - text tags). 
Hope this clarified the situation for you.

Comment: Nowadays it is having the issue if i used anchor text color to white or similar to background color it displayed as black color on docusign.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you set to white, your original document? or the tab color? if you do the former, I find it hard to believe it will become black. I assume you are doing the latter

Comment: It works fine before. But i am facing issues now. Even i set the font color as background color for anchor text it is displaying as black.

Comment: how do you set the color?

Comment: I set forecolor = backcolor for that document. It is working fine before. But now it is having some issues that tags are displayed on Signing process.

Comment: can you share your code? also, when you say "now", what has changed? you changed nothing at all and suddenly you get different results?

Comment: DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.API.Native.DocumentRange[] InitialTagHideResult = doc.FindAll("<<InitTag_" + Convert.ToString(Datarow.Cells["colRimNo"].Value) + ">>", DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.API.Native.SearchOptions.None);
    for (int i = 0; i < InitialTagHideResult.Length; i++)
     {  DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.API.Native.CharacterProperties charProp = doc.BeginUpdateCharacters(InitialTagHideResult[i]);
       charProp.ForeColor = Color.Transparent ;
                                doc.EndUpdateCharacters(charProp);}

Comment: DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.API.Native.DocumentRange[] replaceTagHideResult = doc.FindAll("<<Esign_Initials>>", DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.API.Native.SearchOptions.None);
                            for (int i = 0; i < replaceTagHideResult.Length; i++)
                            {
                                DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.API.Native.CharacterProperties charProp = doc.BeginUpdateCharacters(replaceTagHideResult[i]);
                                charProp.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
                                doc.EndUpdateCharacters(charProp);
                            }

Comment: System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                            Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(richEditControl.RichTextBox.Text.Replace("<<Esign_Initials>>", ""));
                            bytes = richEditControl.RichTextBox.OpenXmlBytes;
                            _docData.msgData = bytes;

Comment: i tried with Color.Transparent as well as Forcolor = backcolor tooo.

Comment: I was thinking you are using the DocuSign  eSignature API. This doesn't look like it. How are you generating the envelope?

Comment: Normal API Request with Signature tags. With anchorString

Comment: I don't see the word "DocuSign" in your code. can you share your entire source?